# Where is numpy log overflow documented?

Tags: python, numpy, precision

Consider these issues of numerical precision:

```
import numpy as np
np.log10(1e-324)   # -inf & divide-by-zero
np.log10(1e+309)   # +inf
np.round(x,  +308) # inf
np.round(x,  +309) # nan
np.round(x,  -308) # nan
```

These numbers are just extreme enough to cause the overflow (?) on my computer.

Where is the relevant documentation for this in numpy? And how may I have predicted exactly these values from it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant full documentation is probably not in NumPy itself, but follows from **IEEE 754** standard.

A very nice explanation of it is in [GeeksforGeeks - IEEE Standard 754 Floating Point Numbers](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ieee-standard-754-floating-point-numbers/).

This standard prescribes results of basic mathematical operation with *non-number operands (infinities, NANs), too* — see the end of the page in my link above — and the floating-point unit (FPU) of your processor follows them when it performs algorithms for NumPy functions (as `np.log10()` or `np.round()` in your examples).

---

Which NumPy (and Python) perform *itself* is

- the implicit conversion of very big numbers (as your `1e+309`) to *infinities*,
- the implicit conversion of very small numbers (as your `1e-324`) to *zeroes*,
- calculating results of their functions by their own (or “borrowed”) algorithms.

---

So `np.log10(1e-324)` is calculated as `np.log10(0)`, which theoretically doesn't exist, but in spite of it the algorithm calculates it using this zero value (effectively calculating the limit).

During performing this calculation occurs division by zero but the algorithm catches the `ZeroDivisionError` exception and raises `RuntimeWarning` instead of it, because it considers this zero value to be a “positive” zero, i.e. dividing (positive or negative) finite number by it *is possible* (giving the result of positive or negative infinity).

The result is then the *negative infinity,* of course, the limit of logarithm of smaller and smaller positive values (“infinitesimally” small ones).

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer! Any idea why `np.log10(1e-323)` (which is below the IEEE minimum) produces ` -323.00518534` (almost the right answer) and not `-inf` ?

Comment: Because `1e-323` **is** in the range for double precision floating point numbers (the other answer in not correct, follow the link in my answer instead), while `1e-324` is **not**. Try `print(1e-323, 1e-324)`.

Comment: Most people think that the range in the other answer is correct, even `sys.float_info` gives such info. But in IEEE 754 are co called **denormalized numbers**, too, which extend the range to subnormal small numbers (at the cost of precision). Denormalized numbers are marked by all 0 bits in their exponent part and are “denormalized” in the sense that there is no assumption of “implicit bit 1” before bits in their mantissa part.

Answer (score 2):

The data type are documented in [Data types](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.types.html) .
NumPy supports `float64` type which gives a range from `1.7976931348623158E+308` to `2.2250738585072014E-308`.